# Contacts App with pictures Sharepoint Online

Tags: app, picture, contacts

I added the Contacts App to my site and synchronized it with my outlook. Now I want the pictures that are in Outlook to be displayed on Sharepoint.

The attachment field shows that there is a ContactPicture.jpg but does not show the actual picture. I then added a calculated column to display the image (as described [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/158546/66181)) and set it up as a number column.

Then I added this formula to the calculated column:

```
="<img src='https://domainname.sharepoint.com/sites/[site]/[subsite]/Lists/[listname]/Attachments/"&ID&"/ContactPicture.jpg' />"
```

But this just displays the IMG tag and source like this:

```
<img src='https://domainname.sharepoint.com/sites/[site]/[subsite]/Lists/[listname]/Attachments/1/ContactPicture.jpg' />
```

Is this method still usable or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you are on SharePoint online site then this solution won`t work. The HTML tags in calculated columns are not supported anymore. You need to find an alternate way to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're running into the recent effects of Microsoft's SharePoint calculated columns update.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032106/handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-fields

The update took effect June 13.

JSLink may provide a workaround for you, but exactly how, I can't advise.